# how to convert array to table in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

In my college days were not learned arrays well. So I am here not familiar in arrays as well how to manipulate them. I have data and I want to put them in table as follows:

```
                  **APRIL 2015**
    DAYS   |  1  |  2  |  3 |  4  |  5  |
   marie   |  3  |  0  |  0 |  0  |  1  |
    anna   |  0  |  2  |  0 |  0  |  0  |
   letty   |  1  |  0  |  1 |  0  |  1  |
    shie   |  0  |  0  |  0 |  0  |  0  |
     sua   |  0  |  1  |  0 |  1  |  0  |  

    TOTAL  |  4  |  3  |  1 |  1  |  2  |
```

The data is composed of agents. I want to create a table that will show how many callers they have in that day. For example in april 1 marie has 3 callers and letty has 1 only and the others don't have so it should display 0. Then below  displays the total calls per day as you see in the above table. I am thinking what would be the flow or the process I should start right now since I am not familiar in arrays. I'm hoping that someone can show me how to do it and I will used it as my reference so next time I know how to do it alone. Thank you in advance.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  
  $scope.agents = [ {
      id:1,
      name: 'marie',
      date: 2015-01-04,
    }, {
      id:2,
      name: 'anna',
      date: 2015-02-04
    }, {
      id:3,
      name: 'marie',
      date: 2015-01-04
    }, {
      id:4,
      name: 'letty',
      date: 2015-01-04
    }, {
      id:5,
      name: 'anna',
      date: 2015-02-04
    }, {
      id:6,
      name: 'shie',
      date: 2015-06-04
    }, {
      id:7,
      name: 'sua',
      date: 2015-02-04
    }, {
      id:8,
      name: 'letty',
      date: 2015-03-04
    }, {
      id:9,
      name: 'marie',
      date: 2015-05-04
    }, {
      id:10,
      name: 'letty',
      date: 2015-05-04
    }, {
      id:11,
      name: 'sua',
      date: 2015-04-04
    },
  ];
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="check">
  <table border="1" width="100%">
    <colgroup span="7"></colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="value in item">
          {{ value }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>

{{agents}}
```

Comment: Have you even tried to do this?

Comment: Yes but I ended up with nothing. I created before a data with tables but they are only basic and simple. So this is too tricky for me now I need help.

Comment: Where is the agents data coming from? Typically this would come from the server and the structure of the data would be changed so it would be returned in a different structure. Can the data structure be changed?

Comment: Yes the data is comes from the database. The structure of the data could be possibly changed  but it's okay, I can handle it.  I just wanted  to learned how to manipulate the arrays and how to put them in table.

Comment: So you want to keep the structure as is and use javascript to transform it to a structure that can be displayed in the table?

Comment: Yes @WayneEllery I want to keep the structure as is and to use javascript to displayed them in the table.

Comment: I don't think it's a technical question rather a logical question..nevertheless can you share plunkr ?